# Wordpress Home page and Index page

Tags: wordpress

How do I make my Index.php page my home page. Please  I am trying to make a slide show on the home page and I don't think it is working because of the Index.php is not set as the home page.

Comment: What code are you using? What is the setting in Wordpress in `Settings > Reading > Front Page Display`?

Comment: I am using a General theme. There is nothing like what you have written in the Settings.  I am using HTML, CSS and the plug in is Weaver Slide Show which I have used before.  I am customizing the theme to fit what I need.  I just can't work out how to make my Home page read the Index.php page.

Comment: what was setting in wordpress in Appearance -> customize -> Static Font page -> Front page displays

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page - put your HTML code on that page(only in Source) and set that as Frontpage in Appearance -> customize -> Static Font page -> Front page displays.That will do the work . :)